# Sonar Ant Task : Invalid value of sonar.sources

Tags: sonarqube, sonar-runner

I am new to sonar. I have written ant script to run sonar. Problem here is If build.xml is kept in root folder of my project then it works fine. But, in our project existing build file is not in root directory of project. I need to integrate sonar-ant-task with existing build script. But, I am getting "Invalid value of sonar.sources" error. I tried all possible ways to configure sonar.source.

Does sonar-ant-task work if build file is not in root dirctory?
Please help me to resolve this iisue

Thanks,
Ganesha

Comment: Please share an error log. You do not give enough information to help you out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer your question, yes, I have the build file not in the root directory and it works. You may want to set the `sonar.projectBaseDir` property. Use `sonar.sources` for the source directories in your project, so that could contain just the value `src`.